# Why can pytest not import my module in a package directory?

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

I have started to study flask using vscode text editor. So, I created some code that can be seen below:

**Folders**

[image]

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app
```

**conftest.py**

```
from delivery.app import create_app


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def app():
    """Instance of Main Flask app"""
    return create_app()
```

**test_app.py**

```
def test_app_is_created(app):
    assert app.name == "delivery.app"
```

Ok, it is a simple example. So, when I try to run on terminal

```
pytest tests --fixtures
```

an error is returned:

```
ImportError while loading conftest 'D:\Projetos Dev\delivery\tests\conftest.py'.
tests\conftest.py:2: in <module>
    from delivery.app import create_app
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delivery'
```

I don't understand why this error happens because I am trying to import a module that exists. Someone may help me to understand it?

Comment: Try adding an empty `__init__.py` file in your `tests` directory

Comment: @mkrieger1 thank you for your answer! I understood some approaches.

Comment: @abc, thank you for your comment. Yes, when I create a `__init__.py` on tests directory the problem was solved!